# Error in query builder in Codeigniter. How can I fetch only records having course_id = 13

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to write this query in Codigniter using query builder:

```
select * from questions where course_id = 13
```

---

What is wrong with this query?

```
$query2 = $this->db->query('select * from questions where course_id = 13 ', false);
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: i mean i got all records from db

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the following code?

```
$this->db->where('course_id', 13);
$query = $this->db->get('questions');
```

Does that work for you?

source: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data